# issues using if exists statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have 2 tables, one is called `TEMP` and the other one is called `MAIN`.  So all what i am trying to do is to check if all records from the `TEMP` table are in the `MAIN` table.  The logic should be all records from temp table must also be in the main table but when i run the sql query here; it does not give me any record and i know there are records missing in the main table from the temp table.  what am i doing wrong here?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT GRP_NM
                 ,GRP_VAL 
          FROM TEMP 
          WHERE GRP_NM + GRP_VAL NOT IN (SELECT GRP_NM + GRP_VAL FROM  MAIN)
         )
  BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO  MAIN(GRP_NM, GRP_VAL )     
   SELECT GRP_NM
        ,GRP_VAL
  FROM  MAIN  
  WHERE GRP_NM + GRP_VAL NOT IN (SELECT GRP_NM + GRP_VAL FROM  MAIN)

  END
```

Comment: What happens when you just run the SELECT GRP_NM, GRP_VAL FROM  MAIN  
   WHERE GRP_NM + GRP_VAL NOT IN (SELECT GRP_NM + GRP_VAL FROM  MAIN) part alone? You appear to be repeating the same logic too, I'm not sure you need the outer if exists at all.

Comment: it returns no value and i know there are almost about 28 records that are missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem has something to do with NULLs. If either GRP_NM or GRP_VAL is null in either table, then GRP_NM + GRP_VAL will be null, and your IN and EXISTS statements get totally bollixed up.

In any case, try this one out:

```
INSERT MAIN (GRP_NM, GRP_VAL)
 select GRP_NM, GRP_VAL
  from TEMP
 except select GRP_NM, GRP_VAL
  from MAIN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO  MAIN(GRP_NM, GRP_VAL )     
SELECT GRP_NM, GRP_VAL 
FROM  TEMP  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM  MAIN
                 WHERE GRP_NM  = TEMP.GRP_NM
                 AND   GRP_VAL = TEMP.GRP_VAL )
```

Answer (score 1):

In second part of your code you are trying to insert values from the same table MAIN (not from TEMP). Maybe just typo.
Try like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT GRP_NM, GRP_VAL FROM TEMP WHERE GRP_NM + GRP_VAL NOT IN (SELECT GRP_NM      + GRP_VAL FROM  MAIN))
   BEGIN 
INSERT INTO  MAIN(GRP_NM, GRP_VAL )     
SELECT GRP_NM, GRP_VAL FROM  TEMP 
WHERE GRP_NM + GRP_VAL NOT IN (SELECT GRP_NM + GRP_VAL FROM  MAIN)

END
```

Comment: The comparison of concatenated values isn't a good idea: `SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' + '1' = 'A   ' + '1' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END`.